# Neo4j Single Query to Refactor Relationships To and From

Tags: neo4j, cypher, refactoring

I have 2 nodes where I want to move all the TO and FROM relationships to the second node.
[image]

//This works FROM
MATCH (c)**<-**[r:HAS]-(f {name: 'ball(a)'}), (t {name: 'ball(b)'})
WITH c, r, f, t
CALL apoc.refactor.**from**(r, t)
YIELD input, output
Return c

//AND this works TO
MATCH (c)-[r:HAS]**->**(f {name: 'ball(a)'}), (t {name: 'ball(b)'})
WITH c, r, f, t
CALL apoc.refactor.**to**(r, t)
YIELD input, output
Return c 
//THIS DOES NOT WORK
MATCH (c)-[r:HAS]**->**(f {name: 'ball(a)'})-[r2:HAS]**->**(d), (t {name: 'ball(b)'})
WITH c, r, f, t, r2, d
CALL apoc.refactor.**to**(r, t)
CALL apoc.refactor.**from**(r2, t)
YIELD input, output
Return c 
I get the ERROR: "Procedure call inside a query does not support naming results implicitly"

**How can I refactor TO and FROM relations in one query?**

Comment: Can you try to put second time  `WITH c, r, f, t, r2, d` between `CALL apoc.refactor.to(r, t)` and `CALL apoc.refactor.from(r2, t)`?

Comment: still get the same error :(

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
MATCH (c)-[r:HAS]->(f {name: 'ball(a)'})-[r2:HAS]->(d), (t {name: 'ball(b)'})
WITH c, r, t, r2, d
CALL apoc.refactor.to(r, t) 
YIELD input, output
WITH c, r2, t
CALL apoc.refactor.from(r2, t)
YIELD input, output
Return c
```

Line number `3` is a function that takes an input `r, t` and as a result returns `input, output`. Inside this `return` you do not have r2 and t, that's why you're receiving an error.

Comment: YOU ROCK!! Thank you!